# How to define path prefix in ServeStaticModule?

Tags: nestjs

I want to serve some static directory structure according to this docs https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static#serve-static but can find answers to these simple questions:

1. How to set up path prefix like '/some/path/to/files'?
2. How to set up serving at runtime (files path is dynamic and can't be hardcoded)?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I saw some answers about `app.useStaticAssets()` but as far as I understood this is Express specific solution and wont compile with latest version anyway (`Property 'useStaticAssets' does not exist on type 'INestApplication'`)...

**Update**

For example I have these directories:

1. /var/lib/app/data1
2. /var/lib/app/data2
3. /home/user/some/path

And I want it to be served as:

1. http://localhost:3000/path1
2. http://localhost:3000/path333
3. http://localhost:3000/my/funny/cats

Comment: `wont compile with latest version anyway` I would suggest you ask this question on a new thread. Support of static content is documented in their official documentation as you noticed. They even included the complete solution which builds and runs with no issues: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/24-serve-static

Comment: Per the official documentation, you have two options: `Under the hood, Nest makes use of robust HTTP Server frameworks like Express (the default) and optionally can be configured to use Fastify as well!` https://docs.nestjs.com/ Serving static content should work with either option.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question but I encountered it for the same problem.

Here is mine, so with the help of the answer of @Jay, which gives the link to all the options available on [github](https://github.com/nestjs/serve-static/blob/6bf8275d7a19b923d09d9287eb6f9aa907b0c291/lib/interfaces/serve-static-options.interface.ts#L4), I was able to find the correct option, which is `serveRoot` when using NestJS ServeStaticModule.

Here is the use case where I used it :

`ServeStaticModule.forRoot({rootPath: '/media/avatar', serveRoot: '/avatar'})`

This line above is to include in your app.module in the import, basically I'm saying that files located in `/media/avatar` should be served on `localhost:1234/avatar`.

Comment: How this can help me to serve many different folders from the different paths and some of them should be determined at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

You asked

> How this can help me to serve many different folders from the different paths and some of them should be determined at runtime?

You can have several ServeRoot declarations, like so:

```
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  serveRoot: '/path1',
  rootPath: `/var/lib/app/data1`,
}),
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  serveRoot: '/path333',
  rootPath: `/var/lib/app/data2`,
}),
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  serveRoot: '/my/funny/cats',
  rootPath: `/home/user/some/path`,
}),
```

as for "determined at runtime", maybe a `ServeStaticModule` can not do this. Others should please correct me on that.

Comment: Nice idea! I didn't think I can use several copies of the module working.

Comment: It doesn't work when using fastify adapter. any idea what can i do for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [renderPath](https://github.com/nestjs/serve-static/blob/master/lib/interfaces/serve-static-options.interface.ts#L9) options on the `ServeStaticModule`. Normally the path is `'*'` so anything that doesn't match your other defined routes attempts to get sent via `res.sendFile()`. If you want to make it `some/path/to/file` you can set `renderPath: 'some/path/to/files/*` and it should work out.

Comment: Maybe my question was too common. I added the example to illustrate what I want. What `ServeStaticModuleOptions` I should pass to achive that?

Answer (score 1):

`rootPath` determines the root of where the static content resides:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
            rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'static'),
        }),
    ],
})
```

In this case the root is the `static` folder.

You can have for example the following structure:

```
static
    page
      png
        sky.png
      index.html
```

In order to get sky.png the request would be: `http://localhost:3000/page/png/sky.png`

In order to get index.html the request would be: `http://localhost:3001/page/index.html`

In addition, here is documentation for `ServeStaticModuleOptions`:
https://github.com/nestjs/serve-static/blob/master/lib/interfaces/serve-static-options.interface.ts

I would point your attention to `renderPath`. I do not find the documentation for `renderPath` very clear but here in this bug report the expected behavior is that the `renderPath` re-maps the local path to URL as you kind of wanted: https://github.com/nestjs/serve-static/issues/26

You can also take a look at Express/Fastify to see how this option is handled there as these are the servers used under the cover.

Comment: I do not see how this all could answer my question or solve the problem in example I provided. Nothing in docs or example covers this situation. If I was blind - please provide what should I pass as `ServeStaticModuleOptions` to achieve that.

Comment: You are asking how to map folder `A` to HTTP request with url `/B`. Actually you asked about how to remap A to B, C to D, and so on. I do not think this is possible. It appears that `renderPath` can do one fixed remapping, A to B. Here, you can see what is needed to achieve that:  https://github.com/nestjs/serve-static/issues/26

Comment: If I were you, I would merge the folders into one using sub-folders and even match the name of the root folder to what you want to use in URL to make it simple. However I do not know anything about your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to get the static file root path from config service then we can do like this

```
ServeStaticModule.forRootAsync({
     imports: [ConfigModule],
     inject: [ConfigService],
     useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => [
     {
       rootPath: configService.get<string>('rootPath'),
     },
   ],
})
```